# How do I run a CLI Python Script from another script

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-module

I'm trying to run this script [here](https://github.com/menahishayan/HomeScript), from another script. When I try to run `import homeScript`, I get given the "help menu" for the script, as shown in the image below.

[image: Help Menu]

What I want to do is to be able to `import homeScript`, and then be able to control the options given in the help menu in my own code. Is it even possible to run it in my own script? I could technically run the script using `os.system()` but that's more of a hack than a solution. Thanks for any input!